# Can other issue types be added to BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I recently started looking at BitBucket again because they now have unlimited private repositories (which I love!). However, there is one more thing that is bothering me before I start using it strictly. When you go to create a new issue, there is a dropdown box there for "type", which contains "bug", "enhancement", and "proposal".

Is there anyway to add new "types" to this dropdown list? For example, "support", "maintenance" etc....It would be awesome if this was more customizable, or at least it if it had more default options.

Comment: Can somebody please add a new tag for bitbucket on this? And remove the programming tag.

Comment: Done. Surprised BitBucket hasn't shown up on here already!

Comment: @Grant Palin me too! I originally asked this question on SO, but somebody directed me here. Pretty soon stackexchange will have a forum for everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you can't.  Jesper has been talking about adding support for that on the mailing list. Hopefully, know that Atlassian bought them, they will have time to add new features instead of server maintenance.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting me know Ryan

Comment: That's a joke! They haven't implemented such obvious thing for past **three years** (WTF?)? I started my journey with BitBucket just a month a go, and when I didn't found tags / labels / other issue types, I assumed that this problem is like month or two old, not three years! Are they supporting BitBucket anyway or they just released to public and forgot about it?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, they added a fourth option at least: "task".

You can also customize your issue tracker by adding [Components](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Adding+Components+to+an+Issue+Tracker), [Versions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Adding+Versions+to+an+Issue+Tracker) and [Milestones](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Adding+Milestones+to+an+Issue+Tracker).

Basically, all three do the same: you can fill a list with possible options in your repository's admin section, and when you create a new bug, you have an additional dropdown box where you can select one of those options.
The selected option is displayed in the issue itself, and in the issue list.

You could "misuse" one of these to add your "support" and "maintenance" stuff.

It's not **exactly** what you were asking for (it's a separate dropdown box instead of adding items to the "type" dropdown box, what you actually wanted), but I think it's the closest that you can get right now.